# How to output the result of a command like :scriptnames in a buffer

Tags: command-line

`:scriptnames` outputs a (not convenient) list with more at the bottom.

I'd like to have all the output in a buffer so i can search, edit ...

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly paste it into the current buffer using

```
:put =execute(':scriptnames')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output to a register like:

```
:redir @a | silent scriptnames | redir END
```

And then past the content of the register wherever you want with `"ap`.

The `silent` is used here, to prevent a "-- More --" prompt.

You could also redirect to file or a script variable. See `:help :redir`.